# How to track the progress of a single function in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix such like:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), nrow = 500)
```

How to track or show the progress bar for a single function:

```
dist(x)
```

I tried a package `pbapply::pblapply(x, dist)` but it seems it calculated the dist for each value rather than for the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I found it can be realized by:

```
pbapply::pblapply(list(x), dist)[[1]]
```

But it might be not the best way.